# Time offset (Paris-Kuwait) incorrect timezone difference SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone

I use a query to filter  records from Friday midnight until Saturday midnight based on kuwait time zone.

First when I check my server timezone I can see:

```
select CURRENT_TIMEZONE();

(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris
```

So I assume that the date column I need to filter is based on this timezone since the records where created and stored on this server, right?

Then I have my query:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    DATETIME,
    DATETIME AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' AS kuwait_time 
FROM
    admin_all.ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL 
WHERE
    DATETIME BETWEEN (DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 5) AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time') 
                 AND (DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6) AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time')
```

Which returns this output:

```
+---------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
| ID      | DATETIME                | kuwait_time                    |
+---------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 1050554 | 2019-12-27 21:05:28.073 | 2019-12-27 21:05:28.073 +03:00 |
| 1050555 | 2019-12-27 21:05:42.586 | 2019-12-27 21:05:42.587 +03:00 |
| 1050556 | 2019-12-27 21:06:58.920 | 2019-12-27 21:06:58.920 +03:00 |
| 1050557 | 2019-12-27 21:07:12.906 | 2019-12-27 21:07:12.907 +03:00 |
| 1050558 | 2019-12-27 21:16:56.436 | 2019-12-27 21:16:56.437 +03:00 |
| 1050559 | 2019-12-27 21:17:10.533 | 2019-12-27 21:17:10.533 +03:00 |
| 1050560 | 2019-12-27 21:17:37.913 | 2019-12-27 21:17:37.913 +03:00 |
| 1050561 | 2019-12-27 21:17:37.986 | 2019-12-27 21:17:37.987 +03:00 |
+---------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Now my issue. Since I want this to start from last Friday at midnight and finish on last Saturday at midnight and since my local DATETIME field is UTC+1, I should have my first record starting at 22:05 to get this starting at midnight Kuwait time Since Kuwait is 2 hours ahead of me (I am UTC+ 1 and Kuwait is UTC+3).

Why I am then filtering first records at 21:05?

**UPDATE:** following @Matt's kind support I came up with this query that takes some of his hints, but also include the last friday and Saturday search in the `where` parameter that was skipped in the answer.

Now query is very slow, there must be a way to speed it up. It  gives a correct results:

```
SELECT id, 
       datetime at time zone 'Romance Standard Time'                                   AS local_time,
       datetime at time zone 'Romance Standard Time' at time zone 'Arab Standard Time' AS kuwait_date
FROM   admin_all.account_tran_all 
WHERE  datetime at time zone 'Romance Standard Time' at time zone 'Arab Standard Time' >= 
       ( 
              SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Sunday' THEN dateadd(day,-2,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Monday' THEN dateadd(day,-3,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Tuesday' THEN dateadd(day,-4,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Wednesday' THEN dateadd(day,-5,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Thursday' THEN dateadd(day,-6,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Friday' THEN dateadd(day,-7,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Saturday' THEN dateadd(day,-8,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                     END ) at time zone 'Arab Standard Time') 
AND    datetime at time zone 'Romance Standard Time' at time zone 'Arab Standard Time' < 
       ( 
              SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Sunday' THEN dateadd(day,-1,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Monday' THEN dateadd(day,-2,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Tuesday' THEN dateadd(day,-3,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Wednesday' THEN dateadd(day,-4,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Thursday' THEN dateadd(day,-5,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Friday' THEN dateadd(day,-6,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Saturday' THEN dateadd(day,-7,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                     END) at time zone 'Arab Standard Time' )
```

the result:

```
| ID          | Original_DATETIME       | Local_time                     | kuwait_date                    |
|-------------|-------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| 1046053     | 2019-12-26 22:00:01.836 | 2019-12-26 22:00:01.837 +01:00 | 2019-12-27 00:00:01.837 +03:00 |
| 1046054     | 2019-12-26 22:00:01.940 | 2019-12-26 22:00:01.940 +01:00 | 2019-12-27 00:00:01.940 +03:00 |
| 1046055     | 2019-12-26 22:00:17.040 | 2019-12-26 22:00:17.040 +01:00 | 2019-12-27 00:00:17.040 +03:00 |
| 1046056     | 2019-12-26 22:00:19.046 | 2019-12-26 22:00:19.047 +01:00 | 2019-12-27 00:00:19.047 +03:00 |
| 1046057     | 2019-12-26 22:00:19.156 | 2019-12-26 22:00:19.157 +01:00 | 2019-12-27 00:00:19.157 +03:00 |
| 1046058     | 2019-12-26 22:00:44.646 | 2019-12-26 22:00:44.647 +01:00 | 2019-12-27 00:00:44.647 +03:00 |
| 1046059     | 2019-12-26 22:00:44.713 | 2019-12-26 22:00:44.713 +01:00 | 2019-12-27 00:00:44.713 +03:00 |
| 1046060     | 2019-12-26 22:00:47.483 | 2019-12-26 22:00:47.483 +01:00 | 2019-12-27 00:00:47.483 +03:00 |
```

Answer (score 2):

> So i assume that the Date field I need to filter is based on this timezone since the records where created and stored on this server, right?

Sorry, but no - that is not right.  There is no implicit binding between the fields stored in your database and the server's time zone.  The server's time zone *is* used by the `GETDATE()` function to determine the local time, but it is subsequently discarded.

For `DATETIME` and `DATETIME2` fields, you must design your database such that you know what the time zone reference is.  For example, often UTC is the reference.  If Paris time is your reference, then you'd have to know that when you do your conversions.

Here's how `AT TIME ZONE` works:

- With `DATETIME` and `DATETIME2` types, the `AT TIME ZONE` statement simply *asserts* the intended time zone.  The result is a `DATETIMEOFFSET` type with the same local date and time as the original value, but with the correct offset for that time zone applied.
- With `DATETIMEOFFSET` types, the `AT TIME ZONE` statement *converts* from the value given to the intended time zone.  A `DATETIMEOFFSET` with the same point in Universal Time is returned, but the date, time, and offset will change to reflect the new time zone.

Thus, if you are starting with a `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` field, you will need *two* `AT TIME ZONE` statements to convert from one time zone to another.

```
SELECT
    DATETIME AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' as paris_time,
    DATETIME AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' AS kuwait_time
    ...
```

The simpler solution is to use `DATETIMEOFFSET` fields to begin with.  Then you won't have to have any implicit knowledge about the time zone reference.

I also suggest declaring local variables for your start/end points.  That will make your code much more readable.

```
DECLARE @NowInKuwait DATETIMEOFFSET = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time';
DECLARE @Start DATETIMEOFFSET = DATEADD(wk, 5, @NowInKuwait) AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time';
DECLARE @End DATETIMEOFFSET = DATEADD(wk, 6, @NowInKuwait) AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time';

SELECT ...
FROM   ...
WHERE DATETIME >= @Start AND DATETIME < @End
```

I'm guessing a bit on your desired start and end times, as the `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` statements in your question do not have the correct parameters.

Also note that I call `AT TIME ZONE` one more time in the declarations for `@Start` and `@End`. That is in case the offset has changed between "now" and the resulting date.  If you're only using this for Kuwait, then you can omit that since Kuwait is fixed to UTC+3.  However many time zones use daylight saving time, or have had changes to their standard time offset, and thus one can't always assume the offsets are consistent.

Comment: very detailed answer. Thanks. Declaring the variables I get an error 'Must declare the scalar variable "@NowInKuwait" Any clue?

Comment: for some reason i get this error after declaring it ...in the @start declaration...

Comment: They need to be all executed together. Are you executing them separately?

Comment: would you mind helping me setting up the query without the declare statements? I need to run this query without them... Thanks!

Comment: You can simply inline them if you need to.  For example: `DATEADD(wk, 5, (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time')) AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time'`.  I think you have enough detail here to complete the query yourself.  Do note that in your original question, you had some strange parameters being passed to `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` functions.  You might want to double check the reference for those before continuing.  Not sure why you need `DATEDIFF` at all really.

Comment: DATEDIFF is used to find the last friday before current date (when query starts) and previous saturday (when it stops). All this at Kuwait time

Comment: so I guess that using : `DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time'),4) at time zone 'Arab Standard Time'` I get the query to start most recent friday at kuwait time

Comment: `DATEDIFF` gives the difference between two dates.  `7` is an integer, not a date.  For `DATEADD`, the parameters are `datepart`, `number`, `date`.  You are passing `datepart`, `number`, `number`.  See docs for [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) and for [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205116/discussion-between-r-life-r-and-matt-johnson-pint).